# Is there an equivalent for Guava Striped-Class in C#?

Tags: c#, concurrency, guava

There are some cases where I really like using [Guava's Striped](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html) class.

**Is there an equivalent in C#?**

Comment: Couldn't you get close by just having an array of `n` objects and locking each `x` on `arr[x.GetHashCode() % n]`?

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't look like there is a direct equivalent, but there are some lockless thread-safe collection options (I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, so I can't say if they will work for your scenario).  Have a look at the [System.Collections.Concurrent Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx).

In particular, ConcurrentBag, ConcurrentQueue, ConcurrentStack, and ConcurrentDictionary all have different locking/lockless thread-safe strategies.  Some are explained in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/01/26/9953725.aspx).

You might be able to get what you want via the [Partitioner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768(v=vs.110).aspx) class, although I am unsure of the implementation.

@Behrooz is incorrect in saying that all .net framework types only use a single lock for the entire list.  Take a look at the [source for ConcurrentDictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs).  Line 71 suggests that this class is implemented using multiple locks.

If you really want to, you could write your own version. The source for the Guava Striped is: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.java

Comment: WRONG, LINE 1863, 1873,1875. btw they don't have any other deadlock prevention mechanisms in place.

Comment: @Behrooz I think you may have read that code wrong. Unless the AcquireLocks method is only ever used to acquire a single lock (which seems pointless, but I don't know) it clearly supports multiple locks.  The comment on line 1875 says that the m_locks collection won't grow, not that it only ever has 1 lock.

Comment: Actually, I've read that code multiple times in the previous years. It locks too much for operations that don't need it. and it locks the bucket 0 for operations that clearly don't need it locked when it's locked(like getting the Count) which causes massive slowdowns in small Collections with multiple reader/writers.

Comment: They implemented a master lock and they decided they didn't need to declare an extra variable. bad design, IMO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will let the bounty being auto-rewarded - should be yours so. :)

Answer (score 6):

I think best you can do is implementing your own because all dotnet framework types offer only one `lock` for the entire list.
To do that you can use the `GetHashCode()` function, modulus(`%`) it with the number of stripes you want. and use it as an index for `Tuple<TLock, List<T>>[]` where TLock can be any kind of lock defined in `System.Threading` namespace and T is the type you want to store/access.
With this you can decide how you want your stripes to be stored. There are choices like `HashSet`(inefficient in your case since you already use some of the bits to calculate the stripe index), `SortedSet`, `List`, `Array`.

btw, Thank you for the question, It's gonna help me solve a problem I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Tamarind](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tamarind/) from NuGet?
It's C# port of Google's Guava library

Comment: Could not find an equivalent class there.

Comment: https://github.com/NextMethod/Tamarind/blob/master/Tamarind/Concurrent/Striped.cs

Answer (score 1):

I think the [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267270(v=vs.100).aspx) can archive a similar result.

Based on their documentation:

> All these operations are atomic and are thread-safe with regards to all other operations on the ConcurrentDictionary class. The only exceptions are the methods that accept a delegate, that is, AddOrUpdate and GetOrAdd. For modifications and write operations to the dictionary, ConcurrentDictionary uses fine-grained locking to ensure thread safety. (Read operations on the dictionary are performed in a lock-free manner.) However, delegates for these methods are called outside the locks to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock. Therefore, the code executed by these delegates is not subject to the atomicity of the operation.

As you can see, read operations are lock-free. That will allow you to not block the threads from reading while other are inserting for example.

Comment: I think you did not get the intention of Guava's Striped class.